# Regex to find text between second and third slashes

Tags: regex

I would like to capture the text that occurs after the second slash and before the third slash in a string.  Example:

/ipaddress/databasename/

I need to capture only the database name.  The database name might have letters, numbers, and underscores.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have only 3 slashes?

Comment: from what context are you running the regexp? the trick with these problems is usually escaping things correctly, and that depends on context.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How you access it depends on your language, but you'll basically just want a capture group for whatever falls between your second and third "/". Assuming your string is always in the same form as your example, this will be:

```
/.*/(.*)/
```

If multiple slashes can exist, but a slash can never exist in the database name, you'd want:

```
/.*/(.*?)/
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be lazy rather than greedy?

Comment: @Isaac shouldn't make a difference if the OP always has exactly three slashes, as I mentioned. If it can be of a different form (i.e. four slashes), the whole question and response would change, and he'd need to specify what he wants to happen in this situation (third slash should or should not be captured) for us to decide which wildcard should be greedy.

Comment: the string does continue with multiple words and slashes, sometimes up to 10.  I should have been more specific, sorry.  a typical example might be /ipaddress/database/issue/issue/issue/issue     etc  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2434549 in that case, you'd want `/.*/(.*?)/`. I've updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 12):

```
/.*?/(.*?)/
```

In the event that your lines always have `/` at the end of the line:

```
([^/]*)/$
```

Alternate `split` method:

```
split("/")[2]
```

Answer (score 5):

The regex would be:

```
/[^/]*/([^/]*)/
```

so in Perl, the regex capture statement would be something like:

```
($database) = $text =~ m!/[^/]*/([^/]*)/!;
```

Normally the `/` character is used to delimit regexes but since they're used as part of the match, another character can be used.  Alternatively, the `/` character can be escaped:

```
($database) = $text =~ /\/[^\/]*\/([^\/]*)\//;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can even more shorten the pattern by going this way:

```
[^/]+/(\w+)
```

Here `\w` includes characters like `A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _`

I would suggest you to give `SPLIT` function a priority, since i have experienced a good performance of them over RegEx functions wherever it is possible to use them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `explode` function with `PHP` or `split` with other languages to so such operation.

anyways, here is regex pattern:

```
/[\/]*[^\/]+[\/]([^\/]+)/
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you specifically asked for regex, but you don't really need regex for this. You simply need to split the string by delimiters (in this case a backslash), then choose the part you need (in this case, the 3rd field - the first field is empty).

- `cut` example:

  ```
  cut -d '/' -f 3 <<< "$string"
  ```
- `awk` example:

  ```
  awk -F '/' {print $3} <<< "$string"
  ```
- `perl` expression, using `split` function:

  ```
  (split '/', $string)[2]
  ```

etc.