# Selecting specific words or phrases in a sentence

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a file which, when read by Java FileReader, prints (println) a bunch of file directories which is in this format:

Z:\123456_tre\12345.mpg;0;2343;3423;43234

I need to find a way so that I can automatically take the *file name* (*12345.mpg*) which is in between the **second back slash "\"** and the **first semi colon ";"** in that line

I believe I have to use regex in order to achieve this, but the light has not come upon me yet.

I was thinking to use a counter variable to count all the slashes. When counter == 2, take the following strings until it reaches a semicolon then stop. Then return the string that was read.

Any help will be fully appreciated! thank you very much!

Comment: You can certainly do it that way but regex would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks! I'm totally going over regex cheetsheet again! haha it is quite confusing if you dont get your head around it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow!

You can of course use RegEx'es, but in this case, you are better using String functions, because they are much, much faster than a RegEx for something as simple as this.

Java provides a function that can be handy: **String.lastIndexOf**, that will search for the LAST occurence of a character, so:

```
  String stuff="Z:\\123456_tre\\12345.mpg;0;2343;3423;43234";
  getFilename(stuff); // will get the filename

  public String  getFilename(String fullFilename) {
       String filename=fullFilename.substring(fullFilename.lastIndexOf("\\")+1); // this will get  12345.mpg;0;2343;3423;43234
       return filename.substring(0,filename.indexOf(";"));
   }
```

Why the double backslashes? (\\)

In Java, and most programming languages, the backslash is a "escape character", that is used for special things like \n (a new line), \r (line feed), etc ... so to use the backslash itself in search functions, you have to escape it.

This is also preferred to the split solutions, because you don't know how deep the filename will be. The solution should work for

```
 z:/directory/directory2/directory4/file.mpg;xxxxx
```

or

```
 z:/directory4/file.mpg;xxxxx
```

Comment: this is fantastic!! I had .lastIndexOf to determine the last occurrence of "\" but did not know what to do after that. Thanks for going the extra mile and sharing some info with doublebackslashes. I hope I could upvote, but I cannot yet..

Comment: don't worry :D the accepted answer is enough. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful:

[Regex to find text between second and third slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825979/regex-to-find-text-between-second-and-third-slashes)

Just adjust to the first slash and semicolon for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        String name = "Z:\\123456_tre\\12345.mpg;0;2343;3423;43234";
        int end = name.indexOf(";");
        String extracted = name.substring(0, end);
        System.out.println(extracted.substring(extracted.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, extracted.length()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `String.split()` ,

```
String input  = "Z:\\123456_tre\\12345.mpg;0;2343;3423;43234";
String output = input.split(";")[0].split("\\")[2];
```