# Regex to find string between slashes

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex (with very little luck) to capture a string that occurs between two slashes in a specific location within a larger string.

An example source string would be:  There will be some text description here followed by the path: `/XYZ/String-needed/ABC/ETC`

The string-needed will always be between the second and third `/` character.

The context of regex for this is within another tool, but it models mostly a java context of regex usage.  I know that the `/` will need to be escaped `\/` but I cannot get the code to find the string between the second and third instance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to find text between second and third slashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825979/regex-to-find-text-between-second-and-third-slashes)

Comment: I saw that answer, but it looked like all the solutions found only the last section of the path and did not account for a continuation past the 3rd slash, so i was always getting ETC returned.

Comment: Have a closer look at the answers from [Adrian Pronk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16826061/2887659) and [Robin Van Persi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16826081/2887659); they both do what you are asking. Demos: https://regex101.com/r/iW3xH3/1 and https://regex101.com/r/iW3xH3/2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use following regex :

```
"^\/[^/]+\/([^/]+)\/"
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/jR9rV5/1

`[^/]` is a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html) which match any string except `/`.