# Regex to match a URL with parameters but reject URL with subfolder

Tags: regex

*Short Question*: What regex statement will match the parameters on a URL but not match a subfolder? For example match `google.com?parameter` but not match `google.com/subdomain`

*Long Question*: I am re-directing a few URLs on a site.

I want a request to `ilovestarwars.com/page2` to re-direct to `ilovestarwars.com/forceawakens`

I setup this re-direct and it works great most of the time. The problem is when there are URL parameters. For example if someone sends the URL using an email program that tracks links. Then `ilovestarwars.com/page2` becomes `ilovestarwars.com/page2?parameter=trackingcode123` after they send it which results in a 404 on my site because it is looking for the exact URL.

No problem, I will just use Regex. So I now re-direct using `ilovestarwars.com/page2(.*)` and it works great accepts all the parameters, no more 404s.

However, trying to future proof my work, I am worried, what happens if someone adds content inside the page2 folder? For example `ilovestarwars.com/page2/mistake`

They shouldn't, but if they do, it will take them forever to figure out why it is redirecting.

So my question is, how can I create a regex statement that will match the parameters but reject a subfolder?

I tried `page2(.*?)/` as is suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825979/regex-to-find-text-between-second-and-third-slashes), but https://www.regex101.com/ says the slash is an unescaped delimiter.

Background info [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), I am using Wordpress and the [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). This [is the article](https://www.doitwithwp.com/regex-beginners-tips-redirecting-traffic/) that goes over the initial redirect I setup.

Comment: But if you manage to get `page(.*?)/` to work and someone enters `ilovestarwars.com/page2?blah` then you'll be back to it failing when someone enters URL parameters because they didn't enter `/`. But you can probably escape the slash with a backslash `\/`

Comment: @pguardiario I wish I could use a library. It is Wordpress and a plugin I am using.

Answer (score 1):

A direct answer to your question would be something like this: `^/([^?&/\]*)(.*)$`

This assumes the string starts at the first `/` (if it doesn't, remove the `/` that follows the `^`). In the first capture group you will get the page name (page2, in the case of your example URL) and in the second capture group, you will get the remaining part of the url (anything following one of these chars: `?`, `&`, `/`, `\`). If you don't care about the second capture group, use `^/([^?&/\]*).*$`

An indirect answer would be that you don't do it this way. Instead, there should be an index page in folder `page2` that uses a [301 redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) to redirect to the proper page. It would make much more sense to do it statically. I understand that you may not have that much control over your webpage, though, since it is Wordpress, in which case the former answer should work with the given plugin.