# SQL Regex to select string between second and third forward slash

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am using Postgres/Redshift to query a table of URLs and am trying to use 
`SELECT regex_substr` to select a string that is between the second and third forward slash in the column.

For example I need the second slash delimited string in the following data:

```
/abc/required_string/5856365/
/abc/required_string/2/
/abc/required_string/l-en/
/abc/required_string/l-en/
```

Following some of the regexs in this [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825979/regex-to-find-text-between-second-and-third-slashes):

```
SELECT regexp_substr(column, '/[^/]*/([^/]*)/')
FROM table
```

None seem to work. I keep getting:

```
/abc/required_string/
/abc/required_string/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about `split_part`?

```
SELECT split_part(column, '/', 3) FROM table
```

Example:

```
select split_part ('/abc/required_string/2/', '/', 3)
```

Returns: `required string`

Answer (score 2):

This may work :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/14ea9/2)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ("c" varchar(29))
;

INSERT INTO t
    ("c")
VALUES
    ('/abc/required_string/5856365/'),
    ('/abc/required_string/2/'),
    ('/abc/required_string/l-en/'),
    ('/abc/required_string/l-en/')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT substring("c" from '/[^/]*/([^/]*)/')
FROM t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/14ea9/2/0)**:

```
|       substring |
|-----------------|
| required_string |
| required_string |
| required_string |
| required_string |
```