# Find and replace between second and third slash

Tags: regex

I have urls with following formats ...

```
/category1/1rwr23/item
/category2/3werwe4/item
/category3/123wewe23/item
/category4/132werw3/item
/category5/12werw33/item
```

I would replace the category numbers with {id} for further processing.

```
/category1/{id}/item
```

How do i replace category numbers with {id}. I have spend last 4 hours with out proper conclusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to find text between second and third slashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825979/regex-to-find-text-between-second-and-third-slashes)

Comment: Thank you. I did look at that. I would like to replace the string instead of finding it in javascript. Looking to do something str.replace(/magix explression/, '{id}');

Comment: In which language are you using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you'll be running regex in JavaScript, your regex will be.

```
/^(\/.*?\/)([^/]+)/gm
```

and replacement string should look like `$1whatever`

```
var str = "your url strings ..."

var replStr = 'replacement'; 

var re = /^(\/.*?\/)([^/]+)/gm;

var result = str.replace(re, '$1'+replStr);

console.log(result);
```

based on your input, it should print.

```
/category1/replacement/item
/category2/replacement/item
/category3/replacement/item
/category4/replacement/item
/category5/replacement/item
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eF2aF0/2)

Comment: Opps ...looks like I accepted the soltuion too quickly :-). The solution seems to fails for

Comment: Opps ...looks like I accepted the soltuion too quickly :-). The solution seems to fails for  /category1/1rwr23/item/action1. Regex is replacing second and fourth token instead of just second

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate the help

Comment: updated try again. Please in your next posts, do provide few different test cases. Original regex was indeed working with provided test strings :)

Comment: Sorry. It was my fault. Will be more concisenext time.

Answer (score 0):

We devide it into 3 groups
1.part before replacement
2.replacement
3.part after replacement

```
yourString.replace(//([^/]*\/[^/]+\/)([^/]+)(\/[^/]+)/g,'$1' + replacement+ '$3');
```

Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9sL1qj87/