# Regex to extract a string between two specific forward slashes

Tags: php, regex

Hi I have the following text:

```
file:/home/dx/reader/validation-garage/IDON/test-test-test@2016-10-04.txt#/
```

I need to retrieve `test-test-test@2016-10-04.txt#` from the string above. If I can also exclude the hash even better.

I've tried looking at examples like this [Regex to find text between second and third slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825979/regex-to-find-text-between-second-and-third-slashes) but having trouble getting it working, can anyone help?

I'm using PHP regex to do this.

Comment: Do you mean any part that has a `@` in it or just last part of path or what?

Comment: [^\/]+\/$ that would give you test-test-test@2016-10-04.txt#/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try regex expression below

```
\/([a-z\-]*\@[0-9\-\.]*[a-z]{3}\#)\/
```

A working example is here: https://www.regex101.com/r/RYsh7H/1

Explanation:

```
[a-z\-]* => Matches test-test-test part with lowercase and can contain dahses
\@ => Matches constant @ sign
[0-9\-\.]* => Matches the file name with digits, dashes and {dot}
[a-z]{3}\# => Matches your 3 letter extension and #
```

PS: If you really do not need # you do not have to use regex. And you may consider using parse_url method of PHP.

Hope this helps;

Answer (score 0):

Without regex you can do:

```
$url_parts = parse_url('file:/home/dx/reader/validation-garage/IDON/test-test-test@2016-10-04.txt#/');
echo end(explode('/', $url_parts['path']));
```

or better:

```
$url_path = parse_url('file:/home/dx/reader/validation-garage/IDON/test-test-test@2016-10-04.txt#/', PHP_URL_PATH);
echo end(explode('/', $url_path));
```

Answer (score 0):

`basename()` also works, so you can also do like this:

```
echo basename('file:/home/dx/reader/validation-garage/IDON/test-test-test@2016-10-04.txt#/');
```